# Regex for SwiftLint custom rule not matching

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftlint

I've created regex to determine if a class has an empty line following it. When searching in xcode, this works perfectly. However, swiftlint does not seem to work properly.

Rule is:

```
custom_rules:
  space_after_class:
    name: "No Space After Class"
    message: "Empty line required after class declarations"
    regex: '(^(open|internal|private|public)*class\s(?!func).*\{$\n(?!^\s*$))'
    severity: error
```

This works fine when searching in xcode/sublime/whatever, but for some reason in swiftlint all class declarations are returned (even those with a new line)

Example of search:
[image]

Example of rule (notice the blank line- this is not found by the same regex using ctrl+f):
[image]

What is different about the swiftlint regex that causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Your yml file needs to be formated correctly. Try validating it with any yaml validators online. 
Seems your regex needs quotation marks " instead of `.

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom rules with SwiftLint is hard as there's no level of validation, like there is with tests for "normal" rules. Try out [AnyLint](https://github.com/Flinesoft/AnyLint) instead which is written exactly to solve this issue. It's written in Swift, but works for any language as it's Regex-based.

Your use case would look like this in AnyLint (I fixed your regex):

```
// MARK: SpaceAfterClass
try Lint.checkFileContents(
    checkInfo: "SpaceAfterClass: Empty line required after class declarations.",
    regex: #"^((?:open |internal |private |public )?(?:final )?class (?!func)[^\n]+\{\n)(?!\s*\n)"#,
    matchingExamples: ["class MyClass {\n  let", "public final class MyClass {\n  let"],
    nonMatchingExamples: ["class MyClass {\n\n  let", "public final class MyClass {\n\n  let"],
    includeFilters: [#".*\.swift"#]
)
```

With AnyLint, you could even provide an `autocorrectReplacement` for autocorrection like so:

```
// MARK: SpaceAfterClass
try Lint.checkFileContents(
    checkInfo: ... // same parameters as above, plus:
    autoCorrectReplacement: "$1\n",
    autoCorrectExamples: [
        ["before": "class MyClass {\n  let", "class MyClass {\n  let"],
        ["before": "class MyClass {\n  let", "class MyClass {\n\n  let"],
    ]
)
```

I hope this helps.